# Searching members of primitive data array assigned at a property in Janusgraph

Tags: gremlin, janusgraph

In Janusgraph, We can assign primitive type array into property of Vertex or Edge.

Sample code.

```
gremlin> arr = new int[2]
gremlin> arr[0] = 0
gremlin> arr[1] = 1
gremlin> g.E(1).property("prop1", arr)
```

Finding the property which has equal array members

```
gremlin> arr2 = new int[2]
gremlin> arr2[0] = 0
gremlin> arr2[1] = 1
gremlin> g.E().has("prop1", arr)
```

But how can I find them with member? (in this case, 0 or 1)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
g.E().filter(values("prop1").unfold().is(0))
```

This query works. but I can't sure its performance is good enough.

Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48371627/gremlin-filter-on-hashmap-property-without-using-a-lambda

Answer (score 1):

I didn't think you could search within arrays with JanusGraph with Gremlin directly as a property value. You'd have to match on the entire array value as you demonstrated. If you wanted to search the values independently of each other (0 or 1 as in your question) you would need to use [multi-properties](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#vertex-properties). Here is an [example from a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49225599/1831717) with JanusGraph.

Comment: Yes. Cardinality.List or Set will work with vertices. But Janusgraph doesn't support Cardinality for edges.